# Can you change a bsoncxx object (document/value/element)?

Tags: c++, json, bson

I'm using the **mongocxx** driver and I am considering keeping the query results given in BSON as a data holder in a couple of objects instead of parsing the BSON to retrieve the values and then discard it.

This would make some sense "**if**" I can edit the BSON on the fly. I couldn't find anything in the **bsoncxx** driver documentation besides the builder that would allow me to manipulate a **bsoncxx** document/value/view/element after it's been constructed.

As an example, imagine that I have something like this

```
fruit["orange"];
```

where `fruit` is a `bsoncxx::document::element`

I can get the value by using one of the `.get_xxx operators`.

What I can't find is something like

```
fruit["orange"] = "ripe";
```

Is there a way of doing this, or the idea behind the builder is "just" to create a query to give to the database?

Answer (score 0):

There was a question with same theme, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453645/change-bson-field-value-c?rq=1)

So, bsoncxx objects seem to be immutable, and we have to re-create them if we need to edit them.. :(

I've written a **really bad** solution which re-creates document from scratch

But this is a solution, I guess.

```
std::string bsoncxx_string_viewToString(core::v1::string_view gotStringView) {
    std::stringstream convertingStream;
    convertingStream << gotStringView;
    return std::move(convertingStream.str());
}

std::string b_utf8ToString(bsoncxx::types::b_utf8 gotB_utf8) {
    return std::move(bsoncxx_string_viewToString(core::v1::string_view(gotB_utf8)));
}

template <typename T>
bsoncxx::document::value editBsoncxx(bsoncxx::document::view documentToEdit, std::string keyToEdit, T newValue, bool appendValueIfKeyNotExist = true) {
    auto doc = bsoncxx::builder::stream::document{};
    std::string currentKey;
    for (auto i : documentToEdit) {
        currentKey = bsoncxx_string_viewToString(i.key());
        if (currentKey == keyToEdit) {
            doc << keyToEdit << newValue;
            appendValueIfKeyNotExist = false;
        } else {
            doc << currentKey << i.get_value();
        }
    }
    if (appendValueIfKeyNotExist) // Maybe this would be better with documentToEdit.find(key), but I don't know how to check if iterator is past-the-end
        //If there is a way to check if bsoncxx contains key, we can achieve ~o(log(n)) [depending on 'find key' implementation] which is better than o(n)
        doc << keyToEdit << newValue;
    return doc.extract();
}
```

Usage:

```
auto doc = document{} << "foo0" << "bar0" << "foo1" << 1  << "foo2" << 314 << finalize;
std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl << std::endl;


doc = editBsoncxx<std::string> (doc.view(), "foo1", "edited"); //replace "foo1" with string "edited"
doc = editBsoncxx<int>(doc.view(), "baz_noappend", 123, false); //do nothing if key "baz_noappend" is not found. <- if key-existance algorythm will be applied, we'd spend about o(lob(n)) here, not o(n)
doc = editBsoncxx<int>(doc.view(), "baz_append", 123, true); //key will not be found => it'll be appended which is default behaviour
std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
```

Result:

`{
    "foo0" : "bar0", 
    "foo1" : 1, 
    "foo2" : 314
}
{
    "foo0" : "bar0", 
    "foo1" : "edited", 
    "foo2" : 314, 
    "baz_append" : 123
}`

So, in your case you can use

```
fruit = editBsoncxx<std::string>(fruit.view(), "orange", "ripe");
```

But, again, [see already-mentioned related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453645/change-bson-field-value-c?rq=1) you're right when saying that

> the idea behind the builder is "just" to create a query to give to the database?

I think, the solution will be "do not edit documents".

> also you can write something like type-converter from bsoncxx to other json storing fomat (for example, rapidjson)
>  Beware of {value:"valid_json"}: bsoncxx::to_json does not add backslashes to quote signs in values => injection can be made.